# when adding @context": "http://www.schema.org" in Js files context error is thrown

Tags: sitecore-client, seo, google-tag-manager

There is review for SEO to include Schema.org for google search
but when added the Json-LD tags as below

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
    "@context": "http://www.schema.org"
}
</script>
```

with customized tag sitecore is throwing following 500 error

```
\Layouts\Default.cshtml(195): error CS0103: The name 'context' does not exist in the current context
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
```

Could you please help how to include schema.org context ? or is there any approach to include in sitecore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@` is a reserved character in Razor views (.cshtml) files. It means that the following text should be interpreted as code.

Just escape `@` character like that:

```
{ "@@context": "http://www.schema.org" }
```

Comment: Thanks @marek, it solved the issue and  one of the key @@Type was missing  @ ,